# how to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ntp/NTPUDPClient

Tags: java

I downloaded commons-net-3.1.jar on this website:

https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient

it worked fine, but now I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ntp/NTPUDPClient

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 1 more

Can someone help me to fix this problem? I already searched for a solution, but I just find android threads without a solution for my problem.

Edit: I am using javaSE-14 (java-JDK) and eclipse. I am using the standard javaSE-14 library and a new created library with commons-net-3.7.jar (from Uroš answer), but I still have the same error. (I am not using a maven projekt, I am using a normal java projekt)
I tried to install the jar into my pom.xml with this text:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>
    C:\Users\denni\Downloads\Apache jar\commons-net-3.7.jar
    </systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I also tried the text that was written below, but I still have the same problem

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>






import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;



public class time {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
             NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient();
             client.open();
             // use host name or IP address of target NTP server
             InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName("pool.ntp.org");
             TimeInfo info = client.getTime(hostAddr);
             info.computeDetails(); // compute offset/delay if not already done
             Long offsetValue = info.getOffset();
             Long delayValue = info.getDelay();
             String delay = (delayValue == null) ? "N/A" : delayValue.toString();
             String offset = (offsetValue == null) ? "N/A" : offsetValue.toString();
    
             System.out.println(" Roundtrip delay(ms)=" + delay
                             + ", clock offset(ms)=" + offset); // offset in ms
             client.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hans and welcome to SO.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is not the same as `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

What is most likely happening to you is that you have included commons-net-3.1.jar, but that doesn't mean commons-net-3.1.jar doesn't depend on some other .jar.

You haven't posted what your classpath looks like or in which IDE you are working in, whatever the case may be I strongly suggest you avoid manually adding .jar files from random sources because:

1. You will get errors like this one, missing dependencies.
2. **More importantly, it is insecure!** You may include some malicious stuff without knowing, and let us be honest here - you sure ain't gonna decompile that .jar and check if it is fishy or not.

Ergo I recommend looking up Maven and how to use it with your IDE, there are plenty of tutorials online about it.

You can use https://mvnrepository.com/ to find the dependecy you need, for example the one you are looking for can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.7), and is currently at version 3.7.
To include it in you maven project all you would need to do is to add it to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using javaSE-14 (java-JDK) and eclipse. 
I am using the standard javaSE-14 library and a new created library with commons-net-3.7.jar (which u had linked in your answer), but I still have the same error. 
Also I tried to insert the text, which u wrote in your comment, in my pom.xml file, but nothing happened at all.

Comment: Well javaSE-14 is quite possibly the source of your problems, it is new and will take a while before libraries catch up with it, Commons lang supports up to Java 11 atm. Generally speaking when developing software that is going to end up in production you really should stick to LTS (Long Term Support) [versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history), check out the link and pick either Java 8  or 11 for now.